# fullcalendar jquery agendaWeek

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to create a timetable functionality using FullCalendar library on AgendaWeek mode.

However when I put several events on the same time slot, it renders horizontally and squeeze the events equally. 
Is it possible to have the events line up vertically and the height of the cell autoexpand.

Also why the hiddenDays function is not working. I'm still looking at a full days from sunday - saturday

I'm using fullcalendar 1.6.1

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

snippet below

```
<script>
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();


        $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
            theme : false,
            header : false,
            minTime : 12,
            maxTime : 18,
            slotMinutes : 60,
            contentHeight : 800,
            height : 1000,
            hiddenDays: [ 1, 3, 5 ],
            allDaySlot: false,
            defaultView : 'agendaWeek',
            editable : true,
            columnFormat : {
                month : 'dddd',
                week : 'dddd',
                day : 'dddd'
            },
            events : [ {
                title : 'Kevin',
                start : new Date(y, m, d, 16, 0),
                allDay : false
            } , {
                title : 'Angga',
                start : new Date(y, m, d, 15, 0),
                allDay : false
            } , {
                title : 'Betty',
                start : new Date(y, m, d, 15, 0),
                allDay : false
            } , {
                title : 'Donna',
                start : new Date(y, m, d, 15, 0),
                allDay : false
            } , {
                title : 'Debby',
                start : new Date(y, m, d, 15, 0),
                allDay : false
            } 
            , {
                title : 'Anton',
                start : new Date(y, m, d, 15, 0),
                allDay : false
            } , {
                title : 'Anton',
                start : new Date(y, m, d, 15, 0),
                allDay : false
            } , {
                title : 'Anton',
                start : new Date(y, m, d, 15, 0),
                allDay : false
            } 
            ]
        });


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try setting the defaultView to the basicWeek. This may be what you are looking for. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/ has all the available views.

```
defaultView : 'basicWeek'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does have the same horizontal events stack up. Problem is, there is no timeslot available to move/add events from one time slot to another. Does adding         minTime : 12,
            maxTime : 18,
            slotMinutes : 60,
  to the basicWeek will render the timeslot ?

Comment: Ah I see your dilemma. I wouldn't know of a way besides updating the framework for the plugin to show the timeslots for a basicWeek view. This may be a feature that is worth running by the author? http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/wiki/Request-a-Feature/